# solr does not index all url's crawled by nutch

Tags: solr, nutch

I am using nutch2.2.1 to crawl Eventbrite.com, but not all url's I received from nutch are not being indexed by solr. 
Eg:`http://www.eventbrite.com/e/10335408485?aff=es2&rank=1`
`http://www.eventbrite.com/e/11176375841?aff=es2&rank=6`
 `http://www.eventbrite.com/e/11276808237?aff=es2&rank=4`
 `http://www.eventbrite.com/e/11454156691?aff=es2&rank=5`
 `http://www.eventbrite.com/e/11595013999?aff=es2&rank=8`
 `http://www.eventbrite.com/e/11898132635?aff=es2&rank=9`

I have received these url, when I crawl , but I am not seeing them in solr admin page. I  have modified the nutch-site.xml file to allow the special characters in url. As I am storing the content of the url's in hbase. I could see that html content of the other urls are being retrieved. But not from these pages. Do I need to modify any other configuration files?

Answer (score 1):

As the above mentioned url's are redirecting urls's I have added the property of 
http.redirect.max to -1. I have made sure the redirected url's are not being filtered by the regex-urlfilters.txt. It work's now.